# Novice question about Git versioning for single user/multiple computer

Tags: git, versioning

Until now id do versionining with subfolder for each version and sync betwen computers with syncthing.
It works but it's easy to do mistake editing wrong version and similar. So I was thinking to switch to some versioning software.
Git seems to be capable to do that and much more. But seems that Git offer to much and I can't see correct way to do.

For example I do make project folder and write .gitignore file with list of files I don't want to be in Git (mostly compiling results)
After that I do write some sources and then issue:

```
git add .
git commit -a -m "the commit remark"
```

And I assume that I need to issue that commands every hour on so. So I can revert if I do some stupid mistake.
Now I have the question when I got some stable code I want to name that as version v1.0. How to do that correctly?
Do I need to make branch or is enought just to make tag?
And when I have v1.0 how to continue work for future v1.1?
Should I work on master or is best to create branch v1.1 and do job here.
If I do some minor change on v1.0 will that appear on v1.1 too?

Now I have 3 computers (work, home, laptop) and I use syncthing to keep all of them in sync. Usually work computer is permanently on and other two on demand. But just I use them.
I do small test and seems that even Git repo is synced ok with syncthing. But I wonder that Git has maybe better way to sync all of my computers. But I don't like to have my code on cloud.
How to manage that?

Thanks for any help

Comment: One approach could be [git-flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), but some people tend to say, it is too complex. You have to find *your* way and at the end it's always some kind of tag/branch mixture you have to use in the way that makes most sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Creating versions

> Now I have the question when I got some stable code I want to name that as version v1.0. How to do that correctly?

Git provides [tags](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) for this. In order to create a tag, use `git tag <tag name>`.

A tag is basically a name for a specific commit. You can check out (get the code) the tag using `git checkout <tag name>`. In order to get the current version of your code again, use `git checkout master`.

### Syncing

> I do small test and seems that even git repo is synced ok with syncthing. But I wonder that GIT has maybe better way to sync all of my computers. But I don't like to have my code on cloud. How to manage that?

git allows you to `push` (upload) your commits to.a git server and `pull` (download) the commits later.

The server (use the computer that is running 24/7) can be created by initializing a bare repository In order to do this, navigate to your server and run

```
git init --bare
```

This creates a new repository without any files checked out (just a server repository).

In order to do push to/pull from a git server, you need to configure a [`remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote).

The easiest way to do this is to use betwork shares. After you can access the share, you can configure the remote like this:

```
git remote add origin /srv/git/project.git
```

or on windows

```
git add origin Z:\your/git/repository.git
```

After creating the remote, you can use `git push -u origin master` and `git pull origin` in order to push/pull.

If you don't want to use network shares, you can use an SSH or smart HTTP server.

More information can be found in [this chapter of Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).

### Other tips

I would not automatically commit and push every hour or similar (for software projects) but every time you change something.

You might also want to create a backup before doing anything you are not sure about. Git allows you to restore lost data in most cases (using `reflog` and `checkout`) but this is a bit more complicated.

Comment: so if I make tag v1.0 and after that v1.1 and some days later v1.2 then I can revert to v1.0. but if I want to change v1.0 (but not the v1.1 and v1.2) I need to make branch?

Comment: If xou want to change the versions, just use `branch` instead of `tag` (creating branches and not tags). In order to change a branch, use `git checkout <branch name>`.

Comment: so if I make tag for each version then all of them are *master. But they are like readonly. If I want to change something I need to make branch and that will leave *master intact.

Comment: If you want to change tags in the future, just use branches instead of tags from the start on. Tags can only be changed by deleting and recreating the tag.

Comment: git allows you to push (upload) your commits to.a git server and pull (download) the commits later.

The server (use the computer that is running 24/7) can be created by initializing a bare repository In order to do this, navigate to your server and run.  Does that server need to store all data or its only gateway.-

Comment: It stores all commits. It basically is another copy of your repository.